# Round-trip safety of storing integer in void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast

In [this article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) the following is mentioned regarding **`reinterpret_cast`** of integers and pointers:

> (the round-trip conversion in the opposite direction is not guaranteed; the same pointer may have multiple integer representations)

Do I understand correctly that the following is then not guaranteed by the standard:

```
intptr_t x = 5; 
void* y = reinterpret_cast<void*>(x);
assert(x == reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(y));
```

Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. The relevant paragraph of the standard is [expr.reinterpret.cast]/5 in C++17:

> A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer. A pointer converted to
>   an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type
>   will have its original value; mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined.
>   [ *Note:* Except as described in 6.7.4.3, the result of such a conversion will not be a safely-derived pointer
>   value. — *end note* ]

Thus, while the mapping from pointers to integers is guaranteed to have a left inverse (and therefore be injective), no guarantee is made that it is bijective; whether or not it is part of the "implementation-defined" behaviour. As cppreference points out, there may be several integers that convert to the same pointer.

Comment: Great answer. If the *mapping from pointers to integers* is *injective*, but not *bijective*, then this mapping is not *surjective*, i.e.: for a given integer there may not be a pointer which converts to this integer.

Answer (score 1):

There might not be an integral type that exactly matches the width of the platform's address space.  `intptr_t` has to be big enough to hold any pointer value, meaning it is as big or bigger than a pointer, and when it is bigger, the pigeonhole principle guarantees that it won't be possible for each integer value to have a unique `void*` value.

Comment: I'd guess most c++ implementations preserve any integer value that fits inside a `void*` when cast back, but the c++ **standard** doesn't even guarantee that apparently (see accepted answer), it is implementation-defined.

Comment: @zse: I'd guess that 100% of practical implementations have a range of values that linearly maps onto the entire set of pointer values.  However, you may find that some preserve a bit range other than the least-significant bits, apply an offset, or perform sign extension (which really is a special case of an offset).